# Compactness of Lukasiewicz Logic

Tags: lo.logic

I'm interested in Fuzzy logic. I have read that the compactness theorem holds for predicate Lukasiewicz  logic, with semantics over $[0,1]$.

However I found the following question on mathoverflow about Godel logic

[Compactness and completeness in Gödel logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160112/compactness-and-completeness-in-g%C3%B6del-logic)

While I realize that the comments under the "EDIT" doesn't apply, it seems to me that you could take a structure, expand the language by adding uncountably many  nullary predicates, and $\{P_{a}|a\in{\omega_{1}+2}\}$  and show that the theory $T$ axiomatized by $\{(P_{b}\rightarrow{P_a})\rightarrow{P_b}|a<b\}$ is finitely satisfiable. But this should lead to a contradiction as in the above question; paraphrasing the answer given there slightly;

However, any model of $T $  where $P_{\omega_{1}+1}$ has truth value $x$, with $x<1$ in its ordering, must have the valuation of $P_{a}$ is less than the valuation of $P_{b}$ for $a<b$ (as the linear order has the property that the truth value of $p\implies{q}=1$ iff $p\leq{q}$ where the ordering here is the ordering on the truth value of algebras), and hence the valuation $v$ provides an embedding of $\omega_{1}+1$ into the algebra of truth values, which should be a contradiction.

My questions are:

Where am I going wrong? If I were to hazard a guess, I would say that since we cannot add $\neg(P_{\omega + 1}\leftrightarrow{1})$ to $T$, any model of $T$ over $[0,1]$ would necessarily have all of the $P_{a}$'s having truth value $1$. Am I correct on this?

Am I correct in stating "as the linear order has the property that the truth value of $p\implies{q}=1$ iff $p\leq{q}$ where the ordering here is the ordering on the truth value of algebras"? This is true in $[0,1]$, and I think it should be true in general, but I'm not a 100%.

Edit: Here by compactness I mean the following: If $T$ is finitely satisfiable over $[0,1]$ then $T$ has a model over $[0,1]$.

Edit2: I would also like to know if the following is true in general: If $T$ is finitely satisfiable over $K$, where $K$ is some $MV$-algebra, then $T$ has a model over $K$.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: Your answer is what inspired the question. I thought I'd tag you here to see if you had further thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Does a tag like this work?  Or can you only tag someone already involved in this question...

Comment: (@GeraldEdgar is perfectly correct. The @ notification didn’t work, but I’ve noticed the question regardless.) “Compactness” can mean several different things that are not necessarily equivalent for nonclassical logics, so you first need to state exactly what you mean by compactness theorem, and what is meant by it in the reference you read. For instance, see Theorem 2 in http://logica.dmi.unisa.it/lucaspada/wp-content/uploads/final-abstract2.0.pdf : as you can see, three formulations of compactness hold for Łukasiewicz logic, but the fourth one does not; beware that the paper only ...

Comment: ... considers *finite* languages with relations and constants, in particular all theories in the statement are countable. The argument outlined in the question can indeed be used to refute (iv).

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: Ah, I didn't know that, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Thank you for the link. I was thinking of definition 1: If $T$ is finitely generally satisfiable then $T$ is generally satisfiable. I think this, in a more generalized,  is known as $K$ compactness sometimes, i.e. if $T$ is finitely satisfiable over $K$, then $T$ has a model over $K$. I would also be interested in knowing if there has been other work done for other  $t$-norm logics along these lines: For example would $K$-compactness work if you place restrictions on the  set of sentences you are working with?

Comment: Also what would be a good source regarding the compactness issues? The handbook doesn't really have much to say on this, at least not in the parts I have read so far. There seem to be a lot issues about compactness left unanswered: If you could point me in the direction of relevant papers I would be much obliged (I'm aware of Cintula et al work on completeness and have read the paper by 
Dellunde on the use of ultra products of fuzzy logic).

Comment: It seems to me that you are still confusing various notions. “Generally satisfiable” means satisfiable with value $1$ in a model valued in an arbitrary MV-algebra. (In particular, the algebras used to satisfy $T$ and its finite subsets may be different.) In contrast, you restrict valuations to the standard $[0,1]$ algebra in the question. “$K$-compactness” is something else entirely: there you consider again valuations in the standard $[0,1]$ algebra, but you ask the sentences from $T$ to have values in the given set $K\subseteq[0,1]$ (as opposed to just $\{1\}$).

Comment: I’m not an expert on these matters. Besides the papers you mention, this http://jigpal.oxfordjournals.org/content/20/1/254.abstract seems to be quite relevant (concerning $K$-compactness), but otherwise I don’t really know where to direct you.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry about mixing up the notions: What I'm really looking for is the following;  if $T$ is finitely satisfiable over $K$, then $T$ has a model over $K$ ($K$ is not necessarily a subset of $[0,1]$. It can be some arbitrary $MV$ algebra).

Answer (score 3):

[It is not an answer to your questions, but it is too long for a comment]

This compactness is a well-known fact of Lukasiewicz.

Such compacteness is a rather straightforward consequence of (the non-trivial result) Theorem 5.4.24 published in Hájek's book "Metamathematics of Fuzzy Logic" https://books.google.es/books?id=JUb9sywOIeYC&pg=PA135 (the result goes back to Chang & Belluce in the 60s)

Let me point out that the previous theorem by Chang & Belluce reduces your compactness question to checking that

- every "finitely satisfiable theory over some MV-chain" is also "satisfiable over some MV-chain";

and this is a particular case of the usual ultraproduct construction in first-order classical logic (notice that Lukasiewicz under the general semantics can be seen as 2-sorted classical first-order theory, one sort deals with the domain of the structure and the other sort deals with the MV chain)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking, but nevertheless let me add thatmy guess is that the statement inside your "Edit 2" is false and that a counterexample can be obtained using the MV-chain known as Chang-algebra [i.e., the one corresponding, using Mundici's functor, to the strong unit $(1,0)$ inside the $\ell$-group $(\mathbb{Z}^2,+)$ with the lexicographic order]

Comment: Because of a homomorphism from the Chang algebra onto the Boolean algebra on {0,1}, the two have the same set of satisfiable formulas. I think you guess wrongly.

Comment: @anemone: You guess right, my intuition was wrong (let me add that in your "proof" you also use the fact that your homomorphism preserves all existing suprema and infina, not just the finite ones; but this is not important in the case of the Chang's algebra)